# Cant Click On AdMob Interstitial Ads

Tags: android, admob

I am implementing Admob Interstitial  ads on my one application.Ads are showing perfectly on screen  but when i try to click for go to  Google Play then its do nothing.Logcat giving me this log when i click on ad but not doing anything.

> START {cmp=com.creatiosoft.tracktheperson/com.google.ads.AdActivity
>   (has extras) u=0} from pid 12595

But on my other application its giving me this when i click on ad.

```
START {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://market.android.com/details?id=com.tencent.mm&referrer=ai=CO
```

Please suggest me where i am wrong.

Comment: Have you publish your app? or in testing mode?

Comment: it has been published tomorrow

Comment: Actually some time its happen till then we did not publish our app. we can't tab on ads. and mind one more thing don't click more time else google will block your admob account.

Comment: You can try my this link-
http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/ad-sense-integration-in-android-display.html

Answer (score 5):

If your app use the WebView component and you put webview.pauseTimers(); in onPause(), so there's the problem. I was going crazy with this error and had to comment line by line until I found the problem.

From Google docs:

pauseTimers

added in API level 1
public void pauseTimers ()
Pauses all layout, parsing, and JavaScript timers for all WebViews. This is a global requests, not restricted to just this WebView. This can be useful if the application has been paused.

Comment: I also encountered the same error and this is exactly the cause

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Admob SDK 20.4.0,
Added the `onAdClicked()` callback to `FullScreenContentCallback`.
Enabled the `onAdClicked()` callback in the `AdListener` class for native ad format.